# input[type=email]:invalid does not work. Says valid emails are invalid

Tags: html, css, forms, email-validation

I am trying to validate email in a form.  The html code I have is as follows:

```
<div class="email-entry desktop-container">
<div id="a"></div>
<form name="form1" action="#">
  <input id="test" type="email" name="text1" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  <input type="image"  src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit">
  <p id="addedText"></p>
</form>
```

The CSS code I have that gets triggered is the following:

```
input[type=email]:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url("/images/icon-error.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 75% 25%;
  }
```

What happens is that when I refresh the page the error icon appears which should not be the case.  Below is the css for the input form:

```
input[type=email] {
    margin-left: 60px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 550px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    color:hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 50px 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

[image: Email Validation]
I am wanting to make the validation like the above. Would this be better done with JavaScript and manipulating the Dom?
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have the `required` attribute on your input, the input becomes invalid when it's empty. So after refreshing, it turns empty and thus becomes invalid.

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bauke/4vacnkuh/).

Comment: If I take out the the required attribute how do I get to activate the CSS code?  As at the moment it just shows the regular response.

Comment: If you mean by "activate the CSS code": "when does it turn invalid", that would be when someone enters an invalid email address.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the "required" attribute, when refreshing the page the input field becomes empty and as a consequence it becomes invalid.